# QTableWidget resizeRowsToContents very SLOW

Tags: performance, qt, resize, row, qtablewidget

I've a QTableWidget that contains over 200.000 rows and 8 columns.
The columns has a fixed size.
The rows has a variable size.
Adding the items to the table is fast (few seconds).

Then the call of resizeRowsToContents() takes almost 60/120 seconds! I see that this call is single thread! (Only one core works).
Can I force MultiThreading ?
How Can I speedup the row resizing ?

Thank you,
Salvo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you might try is to update the `QTableWidget` row-by-row using [`QTableWidget::resizeRowToContents`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#resizeRowToContents)(Note: `Row` rather than `Rows`) with the updates being interleaved with other events in the queue.  Overall the process would still take the same amount of time but your GUI would remain responsive during the process.

Firstly, take advantage of the fact that a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) with a zero timeout will emit its timeout signal whenever the event queue becomes empty.  So code such as...

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, &my_callback);
```

will effectively wait until the event queue is empty and then invoke `my_callback`.  If `my_callback` calls the same line of code then you have a function that automatically invokes itself during the next idle period.

Now write the function...

```
void resize_row (QTableWidget *view, int row, int count = 1)
{

    /*
     * Resize rows `row' -> `row + count - 1'
     */
    for (int todo = count; row < view->rowCount() && todo--; ++row) {
        view->resizeRowToContents(row);
    }

    /*
     * If there are still rows remaining then reschedule.
     */
    if (row < view->rowCount()) {
        QTimer::singleShot(0, [=](){ resize_row(view, row, count); });
    }
}
```

This will invoke `view->resizeRowToContents(...)` on all rows in the range [row, row + count).  If the row index is still less that the row count it will schedule itself for the next idle period with updated parameters.

Now, replace...

```
table_widget->resizeRowsToContents();
```

with...

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, [table_widget, row = 0](){ resize_row(table_widget, row, 10); });
```

Seems to work fine in the basic tests I've done.

Answer (score 0):

Resize has to re-calculate, each row hight and adjust. I would not recommend having this many rows in a single QTableWidget. I would go for a pagination technic or some dynamic loading functionality for this long list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more speed use QAbstractTableModel instead of QTableWidget and override the required functions. This is a simple and good example:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it is this slow, same issue I encountered here. My solution was guessing that roughly 1 character will take ~10 pixels. So I have looped through my columns and measuring the length of the string - taking max * 10 (plus the column header len). Then setting column width directly. Much faster and provides similar result.

```
df: pd.DataFrame
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    max_char = max(max([len(str(x)) for x in df[col].values]),len(col))
    tableWidget.setColumnWidth(i, max_char * 10)
```

This, for my test data of ~50,000 rows by 10 columns took 0.03s compared to about 25s using the `resizeColumnsToContents` method